# Searchbox in HTML and pure javascript to find all the matched anchor tags and display the results

Tags: javascript, html, search

**HTML**

I have a search box and some anchor tags. They can be random links on the page, but I have kept them inside divs to keep it simple. I am not sure how to loop through the elements and check if the link is available on the page.

```js
function search() {
    var i;
    var div;
    var query = document.getElementById('searchbox').value;
    div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i];
    var anchor = div.getElementsByTagName("a");

    for (i = 0; anchor.length; i++) {
        if (anchor.innerHTML.indexOf(query) > -1) {
            document.getElementById('results').innerHTML = "results found";
        }
    }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <head></head>
  <body>
    <input type=text id="searchbox" placeholder=search onkeyup=search() autofocus>
    <div><a href=#>Apple</a></div>
    <br>
    <div><a href=#>ball</a></div>
    <br>
    <div><a href=#>cat</a></div>
    <div id=results></div>
    <br>
  </body>
</html>
```

I would also like to know how to display the results and the number of results...Thanks :)

Comment: The markup is invalid

Comment: Is jQuery out of the table?

Comment: what will be input of the searchbox?

Comment: @VanillaGuy Added an answer for you below

Answer (score 0):

> placeholder=search onkeyup=search()

Should have double quotes around the values like so:

> placeholder="search" onkeyup="search()"

For iterating your divs:

```
let count = 0; //variable for tracking count of links that match
let results = ""; //variable for displaying the results

var i;
var div;
var query = document.getElementById('searchbox').value;
//div = document.getElementsByTagName("div")[i]; //This is a no, only gets first div in collection
//change to this
div = document.getElementsByTagName("div");
//var anchor = div.getElementsByTagName("a"); //Move this inside your for loop

//Iterate your div elements
for (i = 0; i < div.length; i++) {
   //Get any links of this div
   const links = div[i].getElementsByTagName("a");
   //Iterate the links
   for(let j = 0; j < links.length; j++){
        if (links[j].innerHTML.indexOf(query) > -1) {
             //We found a match, add to count and append to string
             count++;
             results += results + "<br/>" + links[j].innerHTML;
        }
   }   
}

//If we found at least one match
if(count > 0{
   document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "results found";
}else{
   document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = "no results found";
}

 //Populate the innerHTML of your elements to display the count (number of results)
 //and the results
 document.getElementById("yourResultCountElementId").innerHTML = count.toString();
 document.getElementById("yourResultsElement").innerHTML = results;
```